# QDialer range issue

Tags: c++, qt, qslider, qdial, qabstractslider

I have problems using a QDial with a very big range.
Using QDials with not too big ranges there is no problem, but using it with big ranges yes, for example:

```
QDial *dial;
dial->setRange(-50, 50) //goes well
dial->setRange(-107000000, 107000000) // goes well
dial->setRange(INT_MIN, INT_MAX) // goes wrong, the QDial gets blocked
```

I need to use a QDial because inherits from QAbstractSlider as QSlider, and i need the same traetment for both of them, QDial and QSlider.

Any suggestion or solution for using the QDial with a range as big as [INT_MIN = -2147483647 -1, INT_MAX = +2147483647] without getting blocked?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"?  And why do you need a `QDial` with such a huge range -- the user couldn't possibly adjust the control with that level of finesse?

Comment: With "blocked" i mean that i can´t move it, it gets blocked.
I need to do this because it is a job requirement, i know that it has no sense a qdial with all this range....BUT, with a QSlider and the same crazy big range everithing goes fine...so, if with QSlider goes fine, why not with a QDial?...or what should i do with a QDial to have the same right behaviour as with a QSlider for the ranges?